# How to add project.json and run.csx in deploying Azure Function using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I am creating a template.json to deploy my Function App using ARM Template. I know we can do this to create a Function in the Function App:

```
{
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "TestFunctionCM",
                "type": "functions",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                "config": {
                "bindings": [
                    {
                    "authLevel": "anonymous",
                    "name": "req",
                    "type": "httpTrigger",
                    "direction": "in"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "res",
                    "type": "http",
                    "direction": "out"
                    }
                ]
              },
              "files": {
                "run.csx": "using System.Net;\r\n\r\n public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)\r\n\r\n {\r\n\r\n     return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, \"Hello from MyFunction\");\r\n\r\n }"
              }
            }
```

But this only works for a very small and simple function. Is there a way to **load script** of **run.csx** and project.json here?

Answer (score -2):

I think this falls into the category of just because you can doesn't mean you should :)  I would encourage you to setup a separate deployment for your code and not use your ARM templates for source code deployment (not really their intended purpose).  Embedding your source code in the ARM template would not be considered a good or practical option as you're likely already seeing the limitations

This can be something as formal as a VSTS Build and Release process or something as simple as setting up a git repository (github, vsts, bitbucket, etc) and deploying your application that way. Deploying via GIT is popular and easy and you can find some more details on how to do that at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment . Even publishing from a developer tool or over FTP is a better option.

Lastly I would suggest looking into building precompiled applications with c# through tools such as Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code. CSX files are great for a quick & dirty need or for playing around but are less ideal for production code. Additionally many of these tools actually make it easier to setup a deployment pipeline for your app.